# Filling a table with data using AJAX, various API calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I have a table with lots of columns, this columns are filled with data received in JSON format from different API sources (jquery ajax).  At beginning I thought this would be a good solution because it lets concurrency very easy (Javascript).

The problem is that the browser easily overloads and closes (Firefox). Can you provide a better approach PHP or JS driven?

Comment: What do you mean "overloads and closes"? Does it run out of memory?

Comment: Pretty difficult to comment on this without seeing exactly what you're doing. Post your code, with sample response data (just a couple of rows worth).

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers can't display an arbitrary amount of data. You need to learn to clean up after yourself. Most frameworks delete the rows which aren't currently visible in the DOM. As the user scrolls, new data is loaded but old data is also forgotten (freeing the memory in the process). If they scroll back, the forgotten data is loaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JQuery DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/)

You can use *Server side processing* feature of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

JqGrid is one of the best solution 
you can check 
[Click Here !!](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)